# How can I have both public and private empty constructor?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, code-first

How can I have both private and public empty constructor? I need an empty private constructor, because I am doing code first with EF.

The [documentation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3820.entity-framework-faq-entity-classes.aspx#Does_the_Entity_Framework_require_objects_with_public_empty_constructors) says:

> Does the Entity Framework require objects with public empty constructors?
>
> While the default generated classes have an automatically supplied public parameterless constructor, there's nothing in the framework that requires that it be public. There must be a parameterless constructor, but it can be internal or private.

My attempt:

```
    public class ImmediatePayment:Payment
    {
            private ImmediatePayment(){}
        
           //Problem
            public ImmediatePayment():basePayment(0){}
            
        //defining number other then 0 would make ImmediatePayment pointless, I could check the value of DeadlineDaysAfterOrder, but it seems really really nice to have a constructior without a number
            public ImmediatePayment(intDeadlineDaysAfterOrder):basePayment(DeadlineDaysAfterOrder){}
            
    }
            
public class Payment
{
      public int DeadlineDaysAfterOrder {get;private set;}
      
      private Payment(){}
      public Payment(int DeadlineDaysAfterOrder)
      {
      this.DeadlineDaysAfterOrder  = DeadlineDaysAfterOrder;
      }
}
```

Comment: so why do you need `public` ?

Comment: You can't have two identical constructor function declarations with different scope modifiers. You could however, declare a public static function to create an object.

Comment: I am _very_ interested to hear about why you think you need this functionality

Comment: The point of having a private constructor is to not allow the object to be publicly constructed.  If you want it to be publicly constructed then you don't want a private constructor.

Comment: @Tigran how would you instantiate a class from a different class with a private  constructor?

Comment: *I need an empty private constructor, because I am doing code first with EF.* Why?

Comment: You shouldn't need any explicit constructors for EF Code First (if these are meant to be entities).  I think you need to give us much more context into why you think you need this.

Comment: @PatrickHofman that was the problem. Constructor is need, but not necessarily private.

Comment: I know that, but why you state that you want/need it?

Comment: @mko: my point is that if you need a private constructor, by design, and now you need public too, there must be something wrong with design. your type does too much *different* things, and you might to consider to split it into multiple different types. if that is not possible, you can have a factory method, still no need for `public` ctor.

Comment: @mko it would help if you told us why you thought you needed the private constructor.  There could be _much bigger issues_ needing to be corrected

Comment: This is a typical X-Y problem.

Comment: the issue was simply my assumption that ef needs a private or internal empty constructor....

Comment: We already know, and you keep repeating that. We just asked *why* you assumed that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman "There must be a parameterless constructor, but it can be internal or private" stuck into my mind as "it has to be" instead of "it can be"

Comment: Where does it say so? We are trying to get on top on the cause of your confusion.

Comment: @PatrickHofman https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3820.entity-framework-faq-entity-classes.aspx#Does_the_Entity_Framework_require_objects_with_public_empty_constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, you can't have both, empty private and empty public constructors in the same class. But you don't need in this case, remove the `private` constructor.

There must be a parameterless constructor, it can be `internal` or `private`. 
But it doesn't have to be `private`, it can be `public` which is also the default if it's generated.

Reference: [Entity Framework FAQ: Entity Classes - Does the Entity Framework require objects with public empty constructors?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3820.entity-framework-faq-entity-classes.aspx#Does_the_Entity_Framework_require_objects_with_public_empty_constructors)

Comment: I thought it HAS to be internal or private. That should do it!

Comment: @mko, I up voted this question. I wish our programmers would reach out and ask questions when they need help, except they don't and it causes trouble for us later in sprints. Sorry you took it the wrong way.

Comment: @mko No need to get rude :) He made a friendly comment and you start insulting. Not needed either ;)

Comment: @maccettura It's already been deleted.